# Use of collective nouns and verbs

Tags: verbs, nouns

I see the British normally use plural form of the verbs associated with collective nouns. An example, "The team have fired its coach" versus "The team has fired its coach". I have been told this is slang that has become mainstream. Any idea as to its real origin?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is hardly slang; it simply reflects the perception of a team as multiple people rather than as a unit, and you'll find it in academic journals and broadsheet newspapers, not just SMS messages. It can be found in American English as well, though more restrictively, e.g. *[The couple are](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/16/us/politics/oregon-governor-john-kitzhaber-and-fiancee-cylvia-hayes-walked-tangled-path-to-exit.html)*. And some nouns always take a plural verb: *The NYPD is investigating* contra *The police are investigating*.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the British use this far more than the US and it doesn't seem to agree with the concept of a collect noun which reflects reference to a group rather than multiples. As an editor of many scientific journals I correct this when found in American journals as it doesn't seem to agree with US standards. Every source I have found in the US confirms that standard English should use singular rather than plural. Frankly, scientists don't use it universally. I find it more common in the sports world.